# vb.net javascript tabmenu click failed

Tags: javascript, vb.net, click, tabmenu

Hi I have problems with the program I made

```
<a hidefocus="hidefocus" href="../wizard/quickwan.asp" target="contentfrm" id="link_User_0_0_2" onclick="clickTabMenu(this.id);" onmouseover="mouseOverLink(this.id);" onmouseout="mouseOutLink(this.id)" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">WAN Ayarlari</a>
```

I need to click here this code is not working

```
Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser2.Document.All
    For Each Web As HtmlElement In allelements
        If Web.GetAttribute("id") = "link_User_0_0_2" Then
            Web.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
```

I need your help

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: the click code is not working

Comment: When you post questions, you need to include code (yep), expected behaviour (inferred from code - so yep) , actual behaviour (nope), any errors and which line he occur on (nope). If you could update your question with the missing info, that would be great. Oh. Please read [ask] - it's really important and helps you provide all the relevant info - Thanks. under Stack Overflow rules, questions that dont include this info are off-topic

Comment: <a hidefocus="hidefocus" href="../wizard/quickwan.asp" target="contentfrm" id="link_User_0_0_2" onclick="clickTabMenu(this.id);" onmouseover="mouseOverLink(this.id);" onmouseout="mouseOutLink(this.id)" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">WAN Ayarlari</a>
I want to click here
I need employee code